# Jackson putting quotes around numeric values from OracleResultSet

Tags: java, json, oracle, jackson, resultset

I'm using the Jackson JSON API to create JSON objects in Java and then print.

My code is similar to:

```
OracleResultSet rs = getMyResultSet();
OracleResultSetMetaData rsmd = (OracleResultSetMetaData)rs.getMetaData();

int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
String[] columnNames = new String[columnCount];
int[] columntypes = new int[columnCount];

for(int i = 1; i < columnCount; ++i) {
    columnNames[i] = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
    columnTypes[i] = rsmd.getColumnTypes(i);
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode node;

String columnName;

while(rs.next()) {
    node = mapper.createObjectNode();

    for(int i = 1; i < columnCount; ++i) {
        columnName = columnNames[i];

        //I have a case defined for every OracleTypes.XXXX, but for brevity I'm only putting the one I'm having issues with here
        switch (columnTypes[i]) {
            case: OracleTypes.NUMBER:
                node.put(columnName, rs.getBigDecimal(i)); //BigDecimal chosen based on: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm
                break;
            default:
                node.put(columnName, rs.getString(i));
        }

        //UPDATE: the next line is the logic error that I had that was casuing the trouble
        node.put(columnName, rs.getString(i));
    }

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(node));
}
```

This all works great. The problem is when I go to print it.

Any values picked up from the `OracleTypes.NUMBER` case are getting quotes, even when they should not be. A sample string that I am getting:

```
{"month":"1","year":"2013","modified":"2013-02-05 13:41:48.0","net":"294.68"}
```

What I want:

```
{"month":"1","year":"2013","modified":"2013-02-05 13:41:48.0","net":294.68}
```

Why is the BigDecimal (or any non-int from my testing) being printed with quotes around it? My understanding is that all real numeric values in JSON should be printed without quotes. I thought it might be a primitive/object issue and tried getting the double value from the BigDecimal but that did not help.

I have tested the program using the debugger and it DOES use the switch-case statement correctly, so that is not the issue.

Comment: Have you turned on the [write numbers as string](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.5/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonGenerator.java#JsonGenerator.Feature.0WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS) feature by mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem with my code. At the end, I had an extra `node.put(columnName, rs.getString(i));` This was overwriting the field each time with a String of the value. Removing it fixed the problem. Sorry for the trouble all.

Answer (score 2):

I've copy paste your code and got the result your expecting (no quotes):

{
    "groups": "books",
    "account": "001",
    "age": 35,
    "net": 9.86
}

this could be a version issue, what version are you using?

I've used the latest jackson version to get above output:
jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar

Comment: No problems either with Jackson 2.4.4

Comment: I am using 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.0' I have updated the code example to show you exactly what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you set the value as double if would probably work for you.

```
node.put("net", node.asDouble(bd.doubleValue()));
```